# Writing Parquet Files in Android

Tags: android, parquet

I've been trying to write parquet files on android for the past couple of days, and have really been struggling to find a solution. My original hypothesis was to just use the java parquet implementation (https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr), but I've since realized that not all java libraries play well with Android. I've gone through essentially dependency hell trying to franken-fit the library into my project, and imported as much as i could before hitting walls such as this one (https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/841).

Does anyone know how I might be able to implement a parquet file writer in Android?

Comment: Just a thought but may have the same issues you are encountering is to use a C/C++ version with [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk). You'll have to move data via JNI, but in the end you are trying to implement a server side file format on a mobile device.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Apparently the C/C++ implementation of parquet is less stable than the Java one, so I'm not sure that's the best option. So I'd tend to agree, parquet just isn't the best option on mobile.